# For Loop not iterating VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am trying to delete an entire row if the values in row i column 2 and row i column 3 are empty. My for loop only iterates once. Any idea why?

```
Sub DeleteEm()

RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To RowCount
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3).Value) = True Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe Row.Count is including some blank rows below where you have data.  Could you simply use `RowCount = Rows.Count` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have made an error which is very common for newbies in VBA.  To correct the error you need to change

```
For i = 2 To RowCount
```

to

```
For i = RowCount to 2 Step -1
```

Your original code is deleting rows within the range over which you are iterating.

Consider what happens when i=4 and you delete the row corresponding to that i.  Row 4 is deleted.  What was row 5 now becomes row 4 BUT at the Next, i becomes 5 so i is now pointing at what was row 6 in your starting range having skipped over what was previously row 5, because that became row 4.

If you use F8 to step through your code whilst watching your sheet you will see it all happen before your eyes.

Comment: This makes so much sense! I've encounter this "beginner error" multiple times while writing the script (for code i didn't include). Of course my data keeps changing position (column)! Thank you!!

Comment: I made this change to my script and it worked, however, I don't understand why it only works when we start from RowCount to 2 Step -1 and not 2 to RowCount Step 1? I thought the negative step was only to make it loop backward since you started at RowCount.

Comment: Read my description of why your original code is wrong again.  If you still don't understand this is probably a hint you should giver up on programming.

Comment: giving up on programming now! Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Rows With Empty Cells in Two Columns

- You could also consider using [`Application.Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) to 'collect' the row ranges in a range and then delete the range in one go.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteEm()

    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rng As Range
    For i = 2 To RowCount
        ' Considering 'blank cells = empty cells + ""-cells'.
        ' Either (For empty cells)...
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
        ' ...or (for blank cells)
        'If Len(Cells(i, 2)) = 0 And Len(Cells(i, 3)) = 0 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Rows(i)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```